# Spring Zuul - Gateway Timeout

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul

I'm seeing a 504 response for a long request using the Spring Cloud Zuul gateway pattern.  The timeout occurs exactly 1 minute after the request was issued.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
zuul:
  ribbon:
    ConnectTimeout: 10000000
    ReadTimeout: 10000000
```

and:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000000
```

and

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
```

None of these prevents the gateway timeout after a minute.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out to be the Idle timeout value of the AWS Elastic Load Balancer.  I increased the idle timeout to 3 minutes and the problem went away.

Comment: just spent a bunch of time going through the same thing.  had very high ribbon and hystrix timeouts on zuul and always got 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUTs right at 60kms.  Bumping the ELB idle timeout fixed it.

Comment: What is the syntax/property for bumping this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this differents configurations :

```
# Disable Hystrix timeout globally (for all services)
#hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: false

# Disable Hystrix timeout for a single service
#hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.timeout.enabled: false

# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (globally)
#hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (per service)
#hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indirectly it helped me get to the root cause.

Comment: Does still work today with spring boot 2? I read some properties have changed.